# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: spring, jndi

**I need to establish a JNDI Datasource connection with Tomcat(9.0.31) in Spring Boot(2.3.3.RELEASE) + Spring Data JPA application. I am using the latest version of Spring Boot & JPA**

**I am getting the following error message at runtime.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:408) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) [catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.31]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:54) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/jndiDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.31]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 80 common frames
```

**I have configured the following**

**tomcat/conf/server.xml**

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/jndiDS" 
      global="jdbc/jndiDS" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootdb" 
          username="root" 
          password="root@123"       
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="20" 
         minIdle="5" 
         maxWait="10000"/>
```

**tomcat/conf/context.xml**

```
<ResourceLink 
    name="jdbc/jndiDS" 
    global="jdbc/jndiDS"
    auth="Container"                   
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Jndi-Setup-SB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Jndi-Setup-SB</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiDS

DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

**UserController.java**

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("users")
    public List<User> getUsersList() {
        List<User> usersList= userService.getAllUsers();
       return  usersList;
    }
}

Rest I have one User.java, UserServices.java, UserServicesImpl.java, UserRepository.java
I also tried to create a file in a file in webapp/WEB-INF/META-INF/context.xml with ResouceLink
Please help to resovle the issue.
```

Comment: interested to know whether/how you solved this issue?